# Building a Debian package from source that DOES contain the /debian folder already

Tags: debian, package

I'd like to give a try on Debian packaging. I've found a good RFP about a program I'd love to use, but it already has `debian/` folder with all the required files.

So what do I do now in order to try to submit this program to official debian repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try persuading upstream to remove `debian/` from their release-tarball, as mentioned [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq):

> If upstream has a debian directory in their releases, you should
>   contact them and ask if they can remove the debian/ directory from
>   their tarball releases. There's no need to remove the debian directory
>   from their revision control system (although if it's out of date they
>   may decide to do so anyway), but at the very least the directory
>   shouldn't appear in releases. If you are upstream yourself, well, you
>   can ask yourself to do it.

If they don't want to do that, you should *repackage* the upstream tarball to exclude the `debian/` directory, and use a slightly modified version.

e.g. if upstream has released `1.666.3` then your re-packaged upstream tarball would be `1.666.3~repack0` (and the Debian package would have versions like `1.666.3~repack0-1`).